# Looking for faster loops for big dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a very simple loop that just takes too long to iterate over my big dataframe.

```
value = df.at[n,'column_A']

for y in range(0,len(df)):
    index=df[column_B.ge(value_needed)].index[y]
    if index_high  > n:
        break
```

With this, I'm trying to find the first index that has a value greater than value_needed. The problem is that this loop is just too inneficent to run when len(df)>200000

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: do u mind sharing a sample dataset and explaining ur usecase with it?

Comment: please show a example of your dataframe and your expected output..i think we don't need loop here, loops are very slow with pandas

Comment: maybe you only need sort_values... and get previous index after sort

Comment: [You shouldnt iterate over dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/9081267) for simple operations, use the pandas / numpy methods.

Comment: why don't you simpy slice ? if you want to cut at a certain index value

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should try to avoid loops with pandas, here is a vectorized way to get what you want:

```
df.loc[(df['column_B'].ge(value_needed)) & (df.index > n)].index[0]
```

Comment: unfortunately, this code still doesn't do what I need. I can't just that the first value that suits my criteria (index[0]). I need to increase the values inside the brackets to find the next value after `n`. That's why I was using a loop

Comment: I have added a `df.index > n` condition inside `loc`, this should work now

Comment: That was it, chief! Thanks a lot for the simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wish you have sample data. Try this on your data and let me know what you get

```
import numpy as np
index = np.where(df[column_B] > value_needed)[0].flat[0]
```

Then

```
#continue with other logic
```